# How to drop certain values after checking a condition on the second column?

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming a df as follows:

```
Product    Time
   1         1
   1         2
   1         3
   1         4
   2         1
   2         2
   2         3
   2         4
   2         5
   2         6
   2         7
   3         1
   3         2
   3         3
   4         1
   4         2
   4         3
```

I would like to only keep those `Product`s whose `Time` is greater than 3 and drop the others.
In the above example, after I do

```
df.groupby(['Product']).size()
```

I get the following output:

```
1    4
2    7
3    3
4    3
```

and based on this, from my main df, I would only like to retain Product 1 & 2

**Expected output:**

```
     Product    Time
       1         1
       1         2
       1         3
       1         4
       2         1
       2         2
       2         3
       2         4
       2         5
       2         6
       2         7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return `Series` with same size like original, so possible filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.groupby(['Product'])['Product'].transform('size') > 3]
print (df)
    Product  Time
0         1     1
1         1     2
2         1     3
3         1     4
4         2     1
5         2     2
6         2     3
7         2     4
8         2     5
9         2     6
10        2     7
```

**Details**:

```
b = df.groupby(['Product'])['Product'].transform('size') > 3
a = df.groupby(['Product'])['Product'].transform('size')

print (df.assign(size=a, filter=b))
    Product  Time  size  filter
0         1     1     4    True
1         1     2     4    True
2         1     3     4    True
3         1     4     4    True
4         2     1     7    True
5         2     2     7    True
6         2     3     7    True
7         2     4     7    True
8         2     5     7    True
9         2     6     7    True
10        2     7     7    True
11        3     1     3   False
12        3     2     3   False
13        3     3     3   False
14        4     1     3   False
15        4     2     3   False
16        4     3     3   False
```

If DataFrame is not large, here is alternative with [`DataFrameGroupBy.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['Product']).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead use [`transform.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) after grouping, check which are greater than ([`gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html)) 3 and use the result to perform [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) on your dataframe:

```
df[df.groupby('Product').Time.transform('size').gt(3)]

      Product  Time
0         1     1
1         1     2
2         1     3
3         1     4
4         2     1
5         2     2
6         2     3
7         2     4
8         2     5
9         2     6
10        2     7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this if you don't plan to use [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) operation and you like to use [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

```
g = df.groupby('Product')
t = g.transform('count')
df['c']=t #new column holding the count
df2=df[df['c'] > 3]
print(df2)
```

---

```
    Product  Time
0         1     1
1         1     2
2         1     3
3         1     4
4         2     1
5         2     2
6         2     3
7         2     4
8         2     5
9         2     6
10        2     7
11        3     1
12        3     2
13        3     3
14        4     1
15        4     2
16        4     3
    Product  Time  c
0         1     1  4
1         1     2  4
2         1     3  4
3         1     4  4
4         2     1  7
5         2     2  7
6         2     3  7
7         2     4  7
8         2     5  7
9         2     6  7
10        2     7  7
```